# What is difference between tf.keras.models.sequential vs tf.keras.sequential?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

What is difference between `tf.keras.models.Sequential()` vs `tf.keras.Sequential()`? I don't understand differences between them quite well. Can somebody explain it to me? I am new to TensorFlow but have some basic understanding on machine learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tf.keras.models.Sequential
```

and

```
tf.keras.Sequential
```

Do the same thing but they are from different versions of tensorflow. By the documentation (TensorFlow 2.0), `tf.keras.Sequential` is the most recent way of called this function.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> tf.keras.models.Sequential==tf.keras.Sequential
True
```

Both are same as of TFv2. You could use the later.

Added in this [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/36326acf6dc625014142ad9cbef665dfaf7ecbd9#).

Answer (score 1):

Keras (keras.io) is a library which is available on its own. It specifies the high-level api.
tf.keras (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) implements the Keras API specification within TensorFlow.

If you intend to stick to the Tensorflow implementation I would stick to tf.keras. Otherwise you have the advantage to be backend agnostic.

=====

update for updated question.

The renaming of the package for `tf.keras.models.Sequential` to `tf.keras.Sequential` must have happened from `1.15` to `2.x` you can either downgrade your tensor flow version or update the code. I'd go for the latter

Comment: i have edited the question. Could you explain it better. I don't find documentation about tf.keras.models.Sequential actually. the documentation only mentions tf.keras.Sequential. I am following some tutorials that uses tf.keras.models.Sequential but does not explain what is happening behind the scene(abstract idea would be ok for me for now).

Comment: I think that's what happened. Because while creating a model with either tf.keras.models.sequential or tf.keras.sequential and training that model produced same result. Thanks. Tensorflow should have mentioned this in the documentation. Would have ben helpful.